# What collation to use for Ukraine?

Tags: sql-server, collation, unicode

We have an accounting program with an SQL Server database and would like to start a Ukrainian version. I am not sure which collation to use: *Ukrainian* or *Cyrillic_General*?

With a non-technical Ukrainian, we compared the collation charts for [Cyrillic_general](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0419.1251.Cyrillic_General_CI_AI.html) and [Ukrainian](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0422.1251.Ukrainian_CI_AI.html) and found only minor differences towards the end of the table. That person thinks *Cyrillic_general* should do fine.

Also, [SQL Server 2012 no longer lists the Ukrainian collation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046(v=sql.105).aspx). Is this a reason for concern?

Any advice which to choose?

Comment: Missing Ukrainian collation on MSDN seems to be documentation issue. `SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() ` sure shows it present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, just to make sure that a collation is available or not, you can test in two ways:

- Check the list of available collations (i.e. `sys.fn_helpcollations()`). Running the following query in SQL Server 2012 and 2014 should return 52 rows:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'ukrain%';
  ```
- Try using the collation:

  ```sql
  SELECT N'a' COLLATE Ukrainian_100_CI_AS;
  ```

  If a collation is not available, it will let you know ;-)

Next, we should see if the collations work as expected (best not to fully trust documentation, right ;-) ?).

To test these two collations, run the following:

```sql
DECLARE @CollationTest TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @CollationTest (Col1) VALUES (N'Ы'), (N'Ю'), (N'Ь'), (N'Ъ'), (N'Я'), (N'Э');

SELECT Col1 AS [Ukrainian_100_CS_AS]
FROM @CollationTest
ORDER BY Col1 COLLATE Ukrainian_100_CS_AS;

SELECT Col1 AS [Cyrillic_General_100_CS_AS]
FROM @CollationTest
ORDER BY Col1 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CS_AS;
```

Results:

```
Ukrainian_100_CS_AS
----------------------------
Ъ
Ы
Э
Ю
Я
Ь


Cyrillic_General_100_CS_AS
----------------------------
Ъ
Ы
Ь
Э
Ю
Я
```

Those two orderings at least match the collations linked in the question (which makes sense given that those collation charts were done in 2009 and the `_100` series of collations came out in SQL Server 2008).

The only difference *seems* to be in the initial sort order of one character: **Ь** (Capital Letter Soft Sign). Is the placement of one character a determining factor? You do need to mirror, as much as possible, the expectations of your customers. But, keep in mind that sort rules and initial ordering changes over the years.

Here are some examples of the Unicode spec for the Ukrainian locale. As you can see, both placements have been correct, though the "current" placement matches the Cyrillic collation, not the Ukrainian collation. The main release history of the locale-specific data starts here: [CLDR Releases/Downloads](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads)

```
http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-1-4/posix/uk_UA.UTF-8.src  (2006)
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_SOFT_SIGN>                    <X5EF0>;<X0005>;<X008F>;IGNORE -- Ь
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_YA>                           <X5EFC>;<X0005>;<X008F>;IGNORE -- Я

http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-1-9/posix/uk_UA.UTF-8.src  (2010)
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_YA>                           <X5D45>;<X05>;<X8F>;IGNORE -- Я
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_SOFT_SIGN>                    <X5D46>;<X05>;<X86>;IGNORE -- Ь

http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-21/posix/uk_UA.UTF-8.src   (2011)
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_YA>
                           <X5D45>;<X05>;<X8F>;<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_YA>        -- Я
<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_SOFT_SIGN>
                           <X5D46>;<X05>;<X86>;<CYRILLIC_CAPITAL_LETTER_SOFT_SIGN> -- Ь

http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-24/common/uca/allkeys_CLDR.txt  (2013)
042C  ; [.1B43.0020.0008.042C] # CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SOFT SIGN -- Ь
042F  ; [.1B5E.0020.0008.042F] # CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YA        -- Я

http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-27/common/uca/allkeys_CLDR.txt  (2015)
042C  ; [.1E56.0020.0008] # CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SOFT SIGN -- Ь
042F  ; [.1E6D.0020.0008] # CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YA        -- Я
```

And to be fair, we should keep in mind that collations handle more than sorting. They handle [casing](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-27/common/casing/uk.xml), transformations, etc.

---

So what should one do? It is probably best, regardless of the rest of this, to **choose the locale that is most common for your customers to be using as their main Windows OS locale**. This will at least give consistent behavior to how everything else *should* be running for them. Run the following to see on your system:

```sql
SELECT os.os_language_version AS [WindowsLocale],
       COLLATIONPROPERTY(N'Ukrainian_100_CS_AS', 'lcid') AS [SQLServerLocale-Ukrainian],
    COLLATIONPROPERTY(N'Cyrillic_General_100_CS_AS', 'lcid') AS [SQLLocale-CyrillicGeneral]
FROM   sys.dm_os_windows_info os;
```

Ask as many of your customers / potential customers as possible to check their Windows setup so that you can plan accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the number of locales a collation applies to should determine your decision. It is true that the difference between the two collations in question seems minor, but it is there nevertheless. It all depends on the target audience, I think. Perhaps the OP's Ukrainian mate is bi-lingual (Russian/Ukrainian), as many are in Ukraine, as I am, in fact. That doesn't mean the established sorting rules should be ignored. Just saying.

Comment: @AndriyM I completely agree. That's why I said it is merely something to consider. I was not dismissing the difference, only saying that if it were not a truly important difference, then all things being equal, go with the one that applies to the larger audience. The question merely states that there is a minor difference. If that difference were in the available characters, then clearly you need to choose the one that has what you need. But it is possible that with all of the same characters, a small sort difference between 3 of the characters _might_ be meaningless. So I was just mentioning.

Comment: The Ukrainian version will be used only in Ukraine, as the program is localized for each country. Now it seems more clear to me that the Ukrainian collation is the preferable option, thanks to your input. I was kinda hoping to keep down the number of collations we use (we already use Cyrillic_general for Bulgaria, which has no separate collation) and to reuse the same SQL Server instance for Ukrainian. As @AndriyM says, the different collations are there for a reason.

Comment: @Primoz: There have been disputes (possibly still going on) among Ukrainians about the "correct" position of `Ь`/`ь` in the alphabet. So actually your question is very reasonable and may not really have an easy answer. However, sticking to the fact that there *is* a specific Ukrainian collation that is related to the Ukrainian locale (and there are no other collations that apply to that locale, based on [the chart here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx)) seems a perfectly safe approach to me.

Comment: @Primoz My first sentence must have been poorly worded and distracted from the rest of what I was saying. I never said that the Ukrainian collation had no purpose or wasn't important. I was suggesting that _maybe_ it wasn't _the_ most important thing. Either way, I have restructured and re-worded my answer to hopefully be much clearer. I have also reworded the ultimate advice to be a statement rather than a question and put it in bold. In the end, the Ukrainian collation does exist for a reason, and it might be an important one, but the main issue for you is what collation your customers use.

Comment: @AndriyM It seems that I worded some items poorly since both you and the O.P. had the same misunderstanding of what I said. So, I reworded and restructured to hopefully be much clearer. I also included some examples of how that character has gone back and forth over the years in terms of its placement (since you mentioned the ongoing debate).

Comment: I hadn't read the latest version of your answer at the time of my second comment. Whatever might have looked as if I still disagreed with you was merely just a further clarification of my point in response to @Primoz. Sorry if my comment gave you the wrong impression. I've read your answer now and it makes sense to me. Thanks for taking the trouble of clarifying your point.

Comment: @AndriyM Understood, and thanks for your clarification :). No problem on the update. It was really my responsibility to do that since it was one of those where I started it not 100% sure of where I was going, and then figured it out but never went back to the beginning to remove the fuzzy part. That and the additional time and questions / discussion helped me see the issue (and what is and isn't important) more clearly. So thanks also for the input.